# HTML select onChange doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html

I am not any kind of proficient in JavaScript.
So I wrote a simple function to use on `HTML SELECT`, but it doesn't work.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function changeFormAction() {

    var value = document.getElementById("format");

    if (value == "freeText") {
        document.getElementById("regularExpression").setAttribute("disabled", false);
    }

}

</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="format" name="customFieldType" onChange='changeFormAction()'>
   ...
</select>

<input id="regularExpression" type=text size=5 name="format" disabled="true">
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: do you get any kind of error

Comment: The issue is something else.. It does hit changeFormAction function on change of customField select list..

Comment: You are checking value of disabled field? Do you really need it? Btw, this works, but i am not sure that this is your intention: http://jsfiddle.net/ew5cwnts/1/ ?

Comment: You right, will fix the question. This is not actually what I meant, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*value* in your code contains the **element** "format". Usually, to get the value, you just add `.value` as suffix. But since this a select/dropdown you'll have to do:

```
var element = document.getElementById("format");
var value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
```

Now *value* and *text* will contain the different strings like below:

```
<option value="thisIsTheValue">thisIsTheText</option>
```

Use either to compare with. I'll use both below to show as an example:

```
function changeFormAction() {
    var element = document.getElementById("format");
    var sValue = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    var sText = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    if (sValue  == "freeText" || sText == "freeText") {
        document.getElementById("regularExpression").removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the "alert" on the value, you right, it returned the element, after your change returned nothing, what could be a reason ?

Comment: The reason could be that the `<input>` doesn't contain anything. you have no _value_ set.

Comment: Yes I have, so it, thank you. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! finally I am getting the right values and also getting into an if statement, but this document.getElementById("regularExpression").setAttribute("disabled", false); still doesn't function ...

Comment: Right, try this: document.getElementById("regularExpression").removeAttribute("disabled");

Answer (score 2):

The issue is something else.. It does hit changeFormAction function on change of customField select list..

```
var value = document.getElementById("regularExpression");
```

is wrong usage..
you should use it as

```
 var value = document.getElementById("regularExpression").value
```

And adding from comments for disabling it also can be

```
document.getElementById("regularExpression").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

This wont work because you are trying to fetch text box value using document.getElementById("regularExpression").value;

But on page load you are not having any thing as default value in text box
You might be needed to fetch value of select box.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ew5cwnts/2/

```
 function changeFormAction(value) {

       if (value == "freeText") {
            document.getElementById("regularExpression").removeAttribute("disabled");
        }

    }
```

HTML:

```
<select name="customFieldType" onchange='changeFormAction(this.value)'>
```